# Pseudo-random select from the limited set of options with given probability

Tags: javascript

so, i am trying to create an ai of a kind.... and i am stuck at this problem.

lets assume we have four options.

a. -23
b. -10
c. +4
d. +80

i have to choose 1 of the above option randomly... but the outcome should not be totally random. the option which have greater values must have grater chance of outcome and negative option must have lower chances of outcome.

i need an equation to accomplish this!

by the way i am doing this in js

```
var a=-23;
var b=-10;
var c=4;
var d=80;

var optiontochoose=(equation which choose an option randomly by giving more preference to option with greater values)
```

Comment: What determines how much more likely one option is, eg. should the '80' item be 10x more likely that the '4' option? 20x more likely?

Comment: First make an array. Sort the array. Pick a random number up to the square of the number of entries, then square-root it and round down. For four entries, the options have 1/16, 3/16, 5/16 and 7/16 chances of being picked. Adjust the power used to get a distribution you like.

Comment: @bendataclear all of these option must maintain a ratio which depends on their values, i cant exactly tell how much preference should be given... but in this question a option must have least chance to be picked up and then b option and then c option and d option must have the best chance! i am not good maths stuff so, it should be depended on their values that all i can say!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you please make it more brief!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am absolutely agree with [@user11260787](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11260787/user11260787). To my best knowledge, the only way to increase the chances of a value of being picked is to increase its presence in your source data.

Considering you wish to use some weights that increase chances not proportionally, I would come up with the following solution:

```js
//source values along with corresponding weights,
//increasing proportionally pick-up probability
const src = [
  {value: -23, chance: 3},
  {value: -10, chance: 5},
  {value: 4, chance: 10},
  {value: 80, chance: 20}
]

//pick randomly, considering weights
const weightedRand = src => 
  src
    .map(({chance, value}) => Array.from({length: chance}, () => value))
    .flat()
    [0|Math.random()*src.reduce((chanceTotal, {chance}) => chanceTotal+=chance, 0)]

//do test run for 1k times to check outcome
const outcome1k = {'80':0,'4':0,'-10':0,'-23':0}
for(let i=0; i<1e3; i++) outcome1k[weightedRand(src)]++
console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(outcome1k).map(entry => [entry[0],entry[1]/1e3])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could push the variables into an array, weigh the options by pushing the ones you want to be more likely more than once then choose a random number in the range of the length of your array.

```
var optionsArray = [a, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d, d];
var chosenOption = optionsArray[Math.round(Math.random()*optionsArray.length)];
```

Comment: i tried it but here comes the problem with negative option... your answer will totally eliminated the outcome of negative option but i do want them to come but not as frequently as the positive no having higher magnitude!

Comment: Please normalize the probability. For example add `23+1` (24) to all values, then proceed with this algorithm

Comment: In my example the chance to get the option a or b should be 3/10. You can make it more even by either adding more of those options into the array or putting in less of the good options.

Comment: weightage you can decide by Math.ceil(num/sum) after normalization

Comment: Note that `Math.round(Math.random() * optionsArray.length)` could produce the the array length as result. This means `undefined` is returned. Use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`.

Comment: To simplify the scenario, imagine having an array with one element. Then a number between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive) is produced. If the result is `0.5` or larger, `Math.round` will round upwards, producing index `1`. However since the array only has one element index `1` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. This solution works by first shifting the entire number list so that the minimum value in the list equals 0. Then add a percentage or static value to each value. Sum all values together and pick a random value based on this total.

[image: visual explanation]

```js
function pickSemiRandom(values) {
  if (!values.length) return; // guard against empty arrays

  var min = Math.min(...values),
      max = Math.max(...values),
      diff = max - min,
      diffZero = min - 0,
      percentage = diff * 0.20,
      shifted = values.map(nr => nr - diffZero + percentage),
      //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      // Offset each numbers to give the minimum value more than 0%
      // change of being picked. The higher the percentage the less
      // influence each value by itself has. An ofset of 0 will 
      // result in a 0% pick chance for the minimum value. You can
      // also change this into a static value instead of a percentage
      // of the difference between minimum and maximum value.
      total = shifted.reduce((sum, nr) => sum + nr, 0),
      randomNr = Math.random() * total;

  for (let index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    randomNr -= shifted[index];
    if (randomNr < 0) return values[index];
  }
  
  console.error("for-loop should aways return");
}

var results = new Array(100).fill([-23, -10, 4, 80])
              .map(values => pickSemiRandom(values));

// log results
console.log(results.join(", "));
console.log(results.reduce((counter, result) => {
  counter[result] = (counter[result] || 0) + 1;
  return counter;
}, {}));
```

You can tweak the value of `percentage` to change value distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For the start, you could treat the values as percent values (even if not mentioned) and take a linear probability and add/subtract the percent value of a value of `25` (`100 / length` of the array).

Then take the sum and normalize the given data for generating a random index of `array`.

```js
function getRandomFn(percent) {
    var parts = percent.map((p, _, { length }) => (100 + p) / length),
        sum = parts.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
        normalized = parts.map((s => v => s += v / sum)(0));

    return () => normalized.findIndex((r => v => r < v)(Math.random()));
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    randomIndex = getRandomFn([-23, -10, 4, 80]),
    l = 1e6,
    count = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: 0 }))),
    index;

while (l--) {
    index = randomIndex();
    count[array[index]]++;
}

console.log(count);
```